# Can I change the JComboBox thumb style?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am getting a strange discrepancy between the preview and actual running of my jar file with a combo box, and it seems to be a default in both of my laptops which are entirely different design. I included a simple example image (below). The combobox does have 36 entries and should only allow one selection - which is why I prefer to use this element type. My issue is a strange look of the combo box thumb (image on right) in comparison with the typical and expected look shown in the image on the right from viewing the Preview Design in NetBeans. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tooq.png)

Scouring the internet I cannot find much that shows this discrepancy. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a matter of "Look and Feel":

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

The Preview Design is using a different default L&F than the environment where you're running the application.

[image: Sample Look-and-Feels]

Comment: Ok thanks. I assume coding in my preference will change it for any user. Is this part of the slider settings, because I don’t see anything applicable under the combo box options.

Comment: I can't answer specifically about Preview Design, because I haven't used that before, but an L&F has to be set programmatically, or else you get a platform default L&F. The L&F applies to all sorts of widgets -- not just scrollbars, but buttons, checkboxes, sliders, progress bars, etc -- all at once, not one type of widget at a time.

Comment: I added a sample image a few different L&Fs.

Comment: Excellent! These tips sent me down the right rabbit hole to get what I needed from the online docs. Thank you!